# Creating a grammar for binary expressions with proper precedence (including parenthesis)

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I have a simple toy program that I'm using to play around with binary expressions. I want the normal rules of precedence to apply with expressions in parenthesis being evaluated first, the mult/div, etc. I have the following code set up and it seems to work, but I'm slightly confused why that is.

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%

start: e { printf("%d", $1);}

e: e '+' e { $$ = $1 + $3; }
   | e '-' e { $$ = $1 - $3; }
   | e '*' e { $$ = $1 * $3; }
   | e '/' e { $$ = $1 / $3; }
   | '(' e ')' { $$ = $2; }
   | NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
   ;
```

For example, if I enter 2 * (4 + 4), it will be evaluated properly as 2 * 8 and not 8 + 4. I'm not sure why this is working. I want to make sure my understanding of this is correct. When the parser encounters `2 * (4 + 4)` it first parses the `2 *` then it sees another `e` rule which is the `(4 + 4)`. It then evaluates the `4 + 4` and then passes this value up so now we are at `2 * 4`?

Is this an okay way to define binary operation rules if I make sure to add the precedence rules? Or am I missing some edge cases (played around with it a lot and haven't found any wrong answers so far)?

Comment: bison does not generate recursive descent parsers. Even so, it's hard to see why you think that parentheses might not work. Perhaps you need to ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 1):

`2 * (4 + 4)` is evaluates as `2 * 8`, because that's the only way these tokens can match your grammar rule patterns. Your grammar rules do not have any phrase structure that recognizes `2 * ( 4` as a unit, separately from the `+ 4` part. The only pattern in your grammar that `(4 + 4)` can possibly match is the `'(' e ')'` pattern. This aspect doesn't have anything to do with the precedence rules.

Associativity and precedence among the arithmetic operators is established by these lines:

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
```

Items on the same line are at the same level of precedence; later lines have higher precedence.

If you miss some edge cases, then Yacc will generally complain about that as "conflicts". There is the risk of creating an unambiguous grammar which operates contrary to your intentions, but ambiguities don't pass through without diagnosis.

Comment: So basically with the way I have constructed the grammar, I have the precedence of parenthesis built in.

Comment: The way you have constructed the grammar is that every rule that has parentheses (just one, so far) has one opening parenthesis in it with a matching closing parenthesis.  No grammar symbol in your grammar matches just an opening parenthesis or just a closing one. Therefore, there is no ambiguity.  We know that if an expression `e` contains any parentheses, they are balanced. That means that `'(' e ')'` has no ambiguity issue: the closing parenthesis goes with the opening one in the same rule; it isn't considered against anything inside `e`.